# C3.js Showing sum of values when mouse over on the title of donut chart

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I am using c3 library for plotting the charts.

Can anyone suggest me that how to get the sum of values as a mouse over event when we bring the mouse over the title of the donut chart in c3.js (Please do not consider tooltip of chart into the picture , its the title of donut for which I require sum as like tooltip)

For example :

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['Monday', 70],
            ['TuesDay', 20],
            ['Wednesday', 30],
            ['Thursday', 50],
            ['Friday', 100]
        ],
        type: 'donut'
    },
    donut: {
        title: "Title" 
    }
});
```

In the above example where the total is 270, I want to display 270 as a mouse over on the title of donut chart.

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1):

You can set a mouseover handler when chart is initialized:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    oninit: function() {
        var total = this
            .config
            .data_columns
            .reduce(function(sum, item) {
                return sum += item[1]
            }, 0)

        this
            .selectChart
            .select('.c3-chart-arcs-title')
            .on('mouseover', function() {
                alert(total) // replace with desired tooltip code
            })
    },
    ...
```

Then you can create any tooltip you want. If you want to repeat c3 tooltip's style, try to inspect *.c3-tooltip-container* element.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/qnsxvr9k/2/)